# Gradient and hessian of a function

Tags: vector-analysis

For function
$$J: \Bbb{R}^d\to\Bbb{R}$$
defined in the following way:
$$
J(x) = c + b^Tx + x^TAx
$$
where:

- c is a scalar
- b is d-dimensional real vector
- A is a positive definite matrix

How to find gradient and hessian of function J? Any tips or a simple example with d=2 is much appreciated

Comment: Yes, I've got a tip. Write out the expressions in terms of the coordinates of $x$ (e.g., $b^Tx = b_1x_1+\ldots+b_dx_d$) and compute the partial derivatives. When finished, put everything back together in matrix notation.

Comment: that helps a lot, thank you!

Comment: what about the last term involving the A matrix, any tips?

Comment: nevermind i got it for some reason i thought that x^T is a column and it is a row

Answer (score 0):

If $J(x) = c + b^Tx + x^TAx$, then $$DJ(x)(v) = b^Tv + v^TAx+x^TAv = (b+2Ax)^Tv,$$since $(v^TAx)^T=v^TAx$ (it is a real number). This means that $$\nabla J(x) = b+2Ax.$$The Hessian is the total derivative of the above, so $${\rm Hess} J(x)(v,w) = v^T (2A)w = 2v^TAw.$$